# Finding a % between 2 numbers

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

so I have a game where a user has a fitness level and I wanted to know if I could do something like this below with the fitness system..

So I have 20 levels of fitness, all listed below.

```
100 XP
200 XP
500 XP
1,000 XP
2,000 XP
3,200 XP
4,500 XP
6,500 XP
9,000 XP
12,000 XP
15,500 XP
20,000 XP
25,000 XP
32,000 XP
40,000 XP
50,000 XP
52,000 XP
70,000 XP
100,000 XP
200,000 XP
```

All this information is stored in a database, and I also have a column for each user called current_fitness_xp and what I want to do is sort of get a % of how far they are to the needed_xp of the next level, so this is what I have so far...

```
<?php
// Test script (Lets pretend we're level 5...)
$startXP = 2000; // Would be the current levels needed_xp
$currentXP = 2623; // Would be the current amount of xp..
$endXP = 3200; // Would be the next levels needed_xp

// it would output something near 50%
```

I then want to put that % in to a bootstrap progress bar.

Comment: So just echo it out as a value for the bar?

Comment: What? I am trying to get the % but how would I get the %? I wont always know the numbers, this is just an example not my actual level or xp..

Comment: You need to calculate the percentage and then echo it out as a value for the percentage bar.

Comment: I know this, but how do I calculate it is what I am asking..

Comment: I'm not following the issue, you have the numbers to calculate, why can't you calculate a percentage?

Comment: I wont always have them numbers.. I am grabbing the real numbers from the database and need to do this with PHP, the numbers I posted just now are just testing numbers to show you what I meant

Comment: Yeah so you still have access to the numbers. Pull them from the database for the user, calculate a percentage, output it as a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **%** of player's progress into the next level can be calculated using the following formula:

```
$progress = ($currentXP - $startXP) / ($endXP - $startXP) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple: You just need to subtract the `$startXP`, like here:

```
<?php
$cXP = ($currentXP - $startXP);
$eXP = ($endXP - $startXP);
$percent = (100 / $eXP * $cXP);
?>
```

And then you can just echo the `$percent`-value. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$percent = round(($currentXP - $startXP) / ($endXP - $startXP) * 100);
// $percent is 51.91666. Round-function makes it 52.

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo($percent); ?>"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
    <?php echo($percent); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

So essentially it'll look like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="52"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
    52%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
$currentXP = 2623;
$endXP = 3200;

//Calculate your percentage:
$percentage = ($currentXP / $endXP) * 100;
?>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $percentage; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;">
    <?php echo $percentage; ?>%
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously you will need to grab the XP data from your database for your user using MySQLi or PDO etc.